# Ansible with GCE - creating VM with static ip fails with "value of external_ip must be one of: ephemeral,none"

Tags: ansible, google-cloud-platform

According to [the Ansible GCE docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/gce_module.html), the **external_ip** attribute represents the "type of external ip, ephemeral by default; alternatively, a list of **fixed gce ips or ip names** can be given".

However when I specify either a (valid / existing) static ip address or static ip name in the external_ip field, I get the error described in the subject line.

Excerpt from my playbook:

```
    tasks:
    - name: Launch instances
      gce:
          name: dev-server
          machine_type: "{{ machine_type }}"
          image: "{{ image }}"
          service_account_email: "{{ service_account_email }}"
          pem_file: "{{ pem_file }}"
          project_id: "{{ project_id }}"
          network: default
          external_ip: 
          - 1.2.3.4
          tags: http-server https-server
      register: gce
```

Note #1 - the above works if I remove the external_ip line completely, but (of course) creates a VM with a non-static IP.

Note #2 - the external_ip value above is (obviously) not the real one (which does indeed exist and was created in the GCE web console prior).

Version info:

- kubuntu 15.10
- Ansible 1.9.2
- python 2.7.10
- pip 8.0.2
- Apache libcloud 0.20.1

Comment: Well it clearly says that it's either ephemeral or a list, so try providing it with a list not just fixed single value.

Comment: Yes, I infact originally tried (and just retried now):  
    external_ip:  
    - 1.2.3.4  
And got the same error:  
msg: value of external_ip must be one of: ephemeral,none, got: ['1.2.3.4']

Apologies - this is my first stackoverflow post, having trouble with formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [1.9 branch source](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/stable-1.9/cloud/google/gce.py) shows that in 1.9 your only options are in fact ["ephemeral" or "none"](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/stable-1.9/cloud/google/gce.py#L447).

The [`devel`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/devel/cloud/google/gce.py) branch seems to be only branch with [the commit](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/commit/44af735ac4dc098ed7437ef2a678b3b79c6805e6) that you need so you'll either need to [build Ansible from source](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html#running-from-source) yourself or wait for that functionality to be more widely released.

Comment: Ok so although the doco says external_ip was added in 1.9, the description of that attribute in the Ansible GCE doco is ahead of the actually released code.

Thanks!

Comment: That line in the documentation is unfortunately talking about the ability to _not_ have an external IP address on your instance: https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/commit/94c1b55744eed7b2cf28cb08326f37f6d7f4c0a6